# How to execute an interactive command from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, shell

I need to execute *kdiff3* command in my desktop machine (localhost) from PHP script (using browser, not command line). I've given permission for the user *www-data* that is executing the scripts to execute kdiff3 using *visudo*. In fact, if I log in as *www-data* I can execute it without problems (*sudo kdiff3 ...*, it's configured to not ask for a password at all).

The problem is when I try to execute this command from a PHP script. I've tried this:

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo kdiff3 -m $file.def.old $file $file.def -o $file");
```

and nothing happens (output is NULL). If I try a non interactive command, like *ls* it works:

```
$output = shell_exec("ls");
```

What's happening? Why cannot execute an interactive command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is an interactive graphical user interface program, so it use KDE and Qt and requires an [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server.

And within a web server (i.e. in `PHP` running for `Apache` or `Lighttpd`) you don't have any X11 server.

So there is no way to use `kdiff3` from inside a PHP script (unless the web server is running on your desktop Linux machine; and then you need to set appropriately the environment, notably `DISPLAY` and probably `XAUTHORITY` environment variable). However you could run a command line program like `diff3` ... (using the `popen` tricks).

Comment: May be I shouldn't say "I need to execute kdiff3 command in my localhost". Better: "I need to execute kdiff3 command in my desktop machine" :)

Comment: Just adding DISPLAY=:0.0 to /etc/environment has make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Try `passthru($cmd)`;

It will allow user's I/O on the Terminal screen.

## Edit (27 january 2024)

`readline()` is a better option.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$invalid = TRUE;
while($invalid) {
    $input = strtolower(readline('Confirm (y/n): '));
    $invalid = !in_array($input, ['y', 'n']);
}
$yes = $input === 'y';
var_dump($yes);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly with interactive TUIs like `vim`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sudo` is waiting for user input, as you have said, it is "interactive" - it has asked you for a password.

You can supply one by using [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to execute the command and get separate I/O streams, so that you can parse the output and supply the password when required.

I have come across scripts that use this approach of `echo "suPassword\n" | sudo cmd` to do this, but I personally have found this to be a bit hit and miss.

Comment: You could configure `sudo` so that it does not ask for a pasword.

Comment: Yes, but that is a *very* bad idea for the web server user, which is why I did not suggest it. Allowing the web server user to do, effectively, whatever it wants is a recipe for serious trouble.

Comment: Agreed, but using `sudo` and `kdiff3` from a web sever is already very bad taste....

Comment: It might just be less harm than writing the password in the application if you really restrict it to a specific command.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: In fact, I have configured *sudo* to not ask for a password. It's writen in my question, but poorly expressed, sorry. This is not the problem.

Comment: @DaveRandom: This script will never be executed in a web server! "I need to execute kdiff3 command in my localhost" Only localhost, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use exec :

$Output= exec( $command ,$dom,$return )

Answer (score 0):

Every interactive command expects a working stdin - this is not given with `shell_exec();`

Use `popen()` and friends or redirect your input from a file. You might still be out of luck, if the file in question checks `ISATTY`