# How to use PHP and AJAX to execute a Maxima command (which needs to input interactively) from the Web browser (localhost)?

Tags: php, ajax, web, interactive, maxima

In Windows, start Maxima in the command line, type `??plot;` command, you will see this.

[image]

then, you need to interact with the command line by selecting the `order number` or `all` or `none`.

Now I want to use PHP and AJAX to create a website (localhost), then when you access the PHP script in localhost, you can interact with the backend Maxima command line to use `??plot;` command in the Website.

So I write a PHP script as follows:

filename: `cmx.php`

```
 <?php
 chdir("D:/Program Files/Maxima-5.30.0/bin");
 $expr = escapeshellarg("display2d:false$ ??plot;");
 // $expr = escapeshellarg("display2d:false$  solve(x^2-1=0, x);";
 $cmd_str = "maxima --batch-string=$expr";

 $res = exec($cmd_str, $out_arr, $return_val);
 $out_str = implode('<br/>', $out_arr);
 echo $out_str.'<br/>';
 ?>
```

This time, when I access `http://localhost/cmx.php`, the content in the Web is:

> Maxima 5.30.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
>
> using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.8 (a.k.a. GCL)
>
> Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
>
> Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
>
> The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
>
> (%i1) display2d:false
>
> (%i2) describe("plot",inexact)
>
> 0: Functions and Variables for Plotting
>
> 1: Gnuplot Options
>
> 2: Gnuplot_pipes Format Functions
>
> 3: Introduction to Plotting
>
> 4: Plotting Formats
>
> 5: Plotting Options
>
> 6: barsplot (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 7: barsplot_description (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 8: boxplot (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 9: boxplot_description (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 10: contour_plot (Functions and Variables for Plotting)
>
> 11: get_plot_option (Functions and Variables for Plotting)
>
> 12: gnuplot_close (Gnuplot_pipes Format Functions)
>
> 13: gnuplot_curve_styles (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 14: gnuplot_curve_titles (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 15: gnuplot_default_term_command (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 16: gnuplot_dumb_term_command (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 17: gnuplot_file_name (Functions and Variables for draw)
>
> 18: gnuplot_out_file (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 19: gnuplot_pm3d (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 20: gnuplot_preamble (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 21: gnuplot_ps_term_command (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 22: gnuplot_replot (Gnuplot_pipes Format Functions)
>
> 23: gnuplot_reset (Gnuplot_pipes Format Functions)
>
> 24: gnuplot_restart (Gnuplot_pipes Format Functions)
>
> 25: gnuplot_start (Gnuplot_pipes Format Functions)
>
> 26: gnuplot_term (Gnuplot Options)
>
> 27: implicit_plot (Functions and Variables for Plotting)
>
> 28: multiplot_mode (Functions and Variables for draw)
>
> 29: plot2d (Functions and Variables for Plotting)
>
> 30: plot3d (Functions and Variables for Plotting)
>
> 31: plotdf (Functions for numerical solution of differential equations)
>
> 32: ploteq (Functions for numerical solution of differential equations)
>
> 33: plot_format (Plotting Options)
>
> 34: plot_options (Functions and Variables for Plotting)
>
> 35: plot_realpart (Plotting Options)
>
> 36: scatterplot (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 37: scatterplot_description (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 38: set_plot_option (Functions and Variables for Plotting)
>
> 39: starplot (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 40: starplot_description (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> 41: stemplot (Functions and Variables for statistical graphs)
>
> Enter space-separated numbers, 'all' or 'none':
>
> Still waiting:
>
> Maxima encountered a Lisp error:
>
> Error in PROGN [or a callee]: Unexpected end of #.
>
> Automatically continuing.
>
> To enable the Lisp debugger set *debugger-hook* to nil.

However if `$expr = escapeshellarg("display2d:false$  solve(x^2-1=0, x);";` in the PHP script, I can obtain the expected results.

Besides, I have seen a similar problem [How to execute an interactive command from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032436/how-to-execute-an-interactive-command-from-php), but it does not work for my problem.

While I want to interact with the command line in the Web continuely, and I hope the contex can be associated to each other.

What should I do ? Is there any effective advices or Web framework to help me implement this Website ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your question, following resources maybe are helpful for you.

I find that, `try.redis`, `web macaulay2`, `web Singular` are all the Web interfaces of the software `redis`, `macaulay2` and `Singular`.

alexmchale/try.redis: A demonstration of the Redis database.  https://github.com/alexmchale/try.redis

[image: try redis]

GitHub - fhinkel/InteractiveShell: Build web apps for interactive command-line tools  https://github.com/fhinkel/InteractiveShell

web macaulay2:
http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/
[image: web-macaulay2]

web Singular:
https://www.singular.uni-kl.de:8003/
[image: web-Singular]

But it seems that, these opensource projects are not implemented in PHP and AJAX.

Comment: These resoures are helpful, but I insist on implementing the Webstie using PHP and AJAX, thanks all the same.